# Can't create unique and fulltext index on the same column

Tags: magento2.3, mysql-indexes, db-schema

My table in db_schema looks like below.

```
<table name="test">
    <column xsi:type="int" identity="true" name="test_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id"/>
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="255" default="" />
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="test_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <index referenceId="TEST_NAME" indexType="fulltext">
        <column name="name"/>
    </index>
    <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="TEST_NAME_UNIQUE">
        <column name="name"/>
    </constraint>
</table>
```

After setup:upgrade I get an error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'TEST_NAME', query was: CREATE TABLE `test` (
`test_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity Id",
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "" ,
CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
CONSTRAINT `TEST_NAME` UNIQUE KEY (`name`),
FULLTEXT INDEX `TEST_NAME` (`name`)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_general_ci"

I know there cannot be two indexes with the same name, so how to customize the index name?
I thought referenceId field indicates the name of index but I was wrong.

I'm using Magento 2.3.5 and MariaDB

Comment: Did you generate a `db_schema_whitelist.json`?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I did

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue when attempting to create an unique constraint and a btree index on the same field.

```
<constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="UNIQUE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_NAME">
    <column name="attribute_name"/>
</constraint>
<index referenceId="IDX_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_NAME" indexType="btree">
    <column name="attribute_name"/>
</index>
```

and i was getting

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name 'PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE_NAME', query was: CREATE TABLE `product_attributes` (
> `entity_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `attribute_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
> `catalog_attribute_code` varchar(64) NULL,
> CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
> CONSTRAINT `PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` UNIQUE KEY (`attribute_name`),
> INDEX `PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` (`attribute_name`)
> ) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Investigating some more, i read the following on [this github post](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27899):

> If you are facing this issue when creating both a unique constraint and index for specific column(s) you can remove the index from the schema. The unique constraint will already create an (unique) index on the column(s).

I personally never heard of UNIQUE contraints to create indexes, but investigating some more i came across [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764120/does-a-unique-constraint-automatically-create-an-index-on-the-fields):

> A unique key is a special case of index, acting like a regular index with added checking for uniqueness. Using SHOW INDEXES FROM customer you can see your unique keys are in fact B-tree type indexes.

So, it looks like you cannot create another index on the unique field. As a workaround, i would suggest you add one more field to the FULLTEXT index so its name won't be the same as the unique field's automatically created index name.